# What would the community user's reputation be if it was actually counted?

Tags: discussion, reputation, community-user

Looking at the community user for SO you can see there are **a lot** of votes. Surely some of those hit the rep cap etc etc. Is it possible that someone could calculate the community user's actual reputation?

Comment: This probably depends on your definition.  Do you mean, what would the reputation be if the Community user actually got rep for upvotes/downvotes on Community Wiki questions/answers?

Comment: @Aar yea I actually didn't think about that but yes. What would it's reputation be if it owned that content.

Comment: Would the reputation cap apply to him as well. if so my guess is that he hit the reputation cap every day ... so its pretty easy to estimate

Answer (score 5):

The community user doesn't own any content to vote *on*. The only thing that could affect its reputation are the downvotes it owns, but even then the system is designed to not allow the reputation of any user to go below 1.

Comment: [Not strictly true.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community?tab=questions)

Comment: @Mechanicalsnail well, it was true when this answer was posted..

Answer (score 2):

Here on Meta, [Community owns 2 questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community?tab=questions) (on moderator elections), https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/111310/november-2011-community-moderator-election and https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/134509/june-2012-community-moderator-election.

They're not community wiki, so Community "should" be earning reputation from them. ([These two are its only rep-earning posts on the entire network.](https://stackexchange.com/users/-1/community)) As of this writing, the posts' scores are (+21 -1) and (+37 -1). Since `37 * 5 < 200`, and the posts were months apart, Community did not hit the rep cap. Therefore, it earned `(21 + 37) * 5 - 2 * 2 = 286` reputation.

To calculate Community's *overall* deserved reputation, considering reputation it spent on downvotes, we must make some assumptions. Its voting record is:

```
50,847 up       16,368 question
 6,595 down     41,074 answer
```

Assume that its fraction of downvotes (6595 / (6595 + 50847) ≈ 0.1148114619964486) is the same between its votes on questions and answers. Then it has given about (0.1148114619964486 * 41074 ≈ 4715.766) answer downvotes, each of which costs 1 reputation.

It also owns anonymous suggested edits. Suppose it has already had at least 500 approved suggestions. Reputation from suggested edits are capped at 1000.

Therefore, its estimated overall score is about

> 1 (initial reputation) + 286 (from upvoted posts) + 1000 (approved suggestions) - 4715.766 (spent downvoting)
>
> ## ≈ **−3,428.766**

Since its "real" reputation is negative, there's no surprise that its reputation shows up as the minimum (1).

Comment: Actually at some point and for some time it used to show the reputation it got from CW posts, see [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77115/eeeek-community-user-got-sudden-rep-boost-how-come) though there is no proof you can see me and other mentioning this.