# Eeeek! "Community" user got sudden rep boost.. how come?

Tags: discussion, reputation, community-user

Until recently [Mr. Community](https://stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community) had one single reputation point, you can see it in this old screenshot:

[image: User Community showing 1 rep on old screen capture]

Now it has over 2K reputation all of a sudden.. what has caused this? Has it affected "real" members as well?

Comment: I *think* this has to do with lot of deleted high-voted offtopic/fun/subjective questions recently. This user owns votes on deleted posts. His rep graph is by the way also weird, it hits 60K.

Comment: @Bal but how deleting question can increase his rep? From the rep graph I came to believe it's related to community wiki: maybe upvote on post made community wiki by Mr. Community increase his rep now where it didn't before?

Comment: The votes of deleted posts has got to be *somewhere*. They won't be recalculated on per-user basis of the original voter. It's the community user who owns them. His rep shall decrease with the time again when the normal flow of deleted spam/junk posts (which are often downvoted) continues. It will however never be less than 1.

Comment: @Bal thanks, this is interesting.. hope that someone will come over and confirm this. :)

Comment: @BalusC, that graph does not go past 2008 (for me, at least). (Community [on Super User](http://superuser.com/users/-1/community?tab=reputation), which came to life July 2009, has no reputation graph at all. Still at 1 there too.)

Comment: -1, that circle clearly isn't free-hand.

Comment: @Shadow: Ignore that, it's just a stupid meta meme.

Comment: @Donal thanks, was starting to fear I've done something wrong.. :P

Comment: And, @Shadow, just like everything else: [it's even documented](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/19775#19775)! ;-) But I like [scary monks](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39782/javascript-tag-showing-up-as-javas-on-main-page) much better!

Comment: @Arj thanks for the link! Makes some things lot clearer now.. :D

Comment: I wanted to keep count, but didn't. It seems like the reputation is kind of steady: 2,694 right now, on SO. And so it was on January 26th, before you even noticed the boost, according [to Google's cache](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:JJS64kPNtKcJ:stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community). Still 1 on SU and SF. Also [its reputation graph](http://stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community?tab=reputation) has changed and goes past 2008 now. It's steady at about 60k since 2008-12-30 (and not in sync with the 2,694 reputation it shows).

Comment: @Arjan: this is definitely vague.

Comment: I was wrong: the graph is not steady at all, @BalusC. On October 20th [Community started a bounty of 500 points](http://i.imgur.com/NCJzu.png) on [Directed graph SQL](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/3957486/revisions), and awarded it [without being seen](http://i.imgur.com/odPCv.png)! Community must be Jeff's sockpuppet! ;-)

Comment: At 2,242 on SO right now, so some decrease from the February 11th 2,694 though the reputation overview shows no changes since January 28th. On MSO, it's at 33. On SU it increased from 1 to 210, on SF from 1 to 170. And SU [shows](http://superuser.com/users/-1/community?tab=reputation#reppage_1-repview_post) a funny [0 reputation gain](http://i.imgur.com/uO10z.png) for an accepted answer...

Comment: @Arjan - any idea what's the reason behind those changes? Does it have mind of its own? ;)

Comment: I've no clue, but I am very curious. Maybe this needs some bumping to the front page. Not sure what's the best time to meet some SE developers here :-)

Comment: @Arjan - think I found a way to bump this! :D

Comment: Oy[.](http://google.com)

Comment: @Chichiray, your 2nd comment about decreasing might very well explain the current lower reputation of Community on SO. (Maybe post your two comments as an answer then?)

Comment: Just FYI, community now takes over the bounty for users who are deleted but have an active bounty...to ensure it's awarded (half, since it has to be awarded automatically) correctly, since users did put extra effort into answering those questions in many cases.

Comment: @Richard thanks, wasn't aware the standard was triple `e`!

Comment: (Still at 2,242 on SO, 210 on SU and 170 on SF today. But back from 33 to 1 on MSO...)

Comment: @Nick I'd like to flag your comment as "should be an answer"

Comment: @Tobias question is, is this the only reason for the unstable reputation behavior? See Arjan new comment. :/

Comment: It's even [stealing reputation from moderators now](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116339/community-user-dismissing-close-flags-as-helpful-stealing-credit-from-mods) ;-)

Comment: @Arjan lol! Poor bot became greedy.. :-P

Comment: I just noticed [it's back to 1](http://stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community) nowadays, and all historical reputation changes are gone (or : hidden). Same for Super User. Might have been like that for a long time already.

Comment: @Arjan yeah, noticed this some time ago as well plus it no longer show all sites under its Accounts section (although it's showing nicely in its [network profile](http://stackexchange.com/users/-1/community?tab=accounts) :)) so guess it's finally sorted out. Now what makes me curious how it managed to collect [some favorites](http://stackexchange.com/users/-1/community?tab=favorites)? ;)

Comment: Hilarious! Ah, and there's still [one Community question](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/2/sharepoint-2010-books-to-prepare-dev-focus) ;-)

Answer (score 8):

Just **a wild guess**: edits proposed by *unregistered* low reputation users show as [made by Community](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75472/community-user-edit-how-does-it-know-what-to-edit). Maybe Community is then also earning the reputation for that? From [an old comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/75581/84237):

> There may be a capped reputation incentive (at the moment we are thinking you can get up to 1000 points 2 at a time for good edits)

Not sure if this is indeed implemented! Given the large increase of reputation, I guess the team might have been using unregistered users to test. On the other hand: *at the time of writing this*, on Super User the reputation was still 1, despite [approved edits](https://superuser.com/posts/13418/revisions).

Comment: I suspect that we will find that out when we really need him.

Comment: The [Super User Community user](http://superuser.com/users/-1/community) has now around 200 rep...

Comment: Yup, @Fretje, see the comments on the question itself.

Comment: This looks about right. The rep goes somewhere, why not the bot? Bots have desires too.

Answer (score 4):

If you check [his reputation graph](https://stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community?tab=reputation), you'll see that his rep seems to come from Community Wiki posts.

Comment: Yep but those posts were there for long time - wonder what has changed..

Comment: Indeed, like @Shadow says: what has changed? And above all: I cannot get that graph to go past 2008. And even then it was already 60k. But so far that always showed as 1. Community [on Super User](http://superuser.com/users/-1/community?tab=reputation) (which came to life July 2009) has no reputation graph at all.

Comment: Ah, [the reputation graph](http://stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community?tab=reputation) has been fixed. Almost steady at about 60k since 2008-12-30, but on October 20th [Community started a bounty of 500 points](http://i.imgur.com/NCJzu.png) on [Directed graph SQL](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/3957486/revisions).