# Does bounty dissapear if it isn't awarded?

Tags: discussion, bounties

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does the bounty system work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work)

I put +250 bounty on:

[Replicate PHPBB password hashing in ASP.net c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5376494/replicate-phpbb-password-hashing-in-asp-net-c)

No answers - I felt - answered the question to a satisfactory degree, so I didn't award the bounty.  But when the bounty expired, I was expecting the bounty to credit back to my account, but it didn't: it just dissipated into the void, which is a shame.

Is it meant to do that?  That's ok if it is.  But it seems a shame my 250 rep I have earned has just vanished; if I knew that was going to happen I would have awarded it to the best answer.

Comment: Yeah, if there is no new +2 voted answer after bounty started

Comment: I fell in this too in [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77115/eeeek-community-user-got-sudden-rep-boost-how-come), assuming the +50 bounty will go to Arjan, not knowing the "answers posted after the bounty started" pit. :/

Comment: There must be a bounty recovery if there is not a real answer, actual way sucks at all, so if there is a answer with +2 so 1/2 goes to him even if that answer is not real, or its like a comment. Bounty must be recovered.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes half of your bounty will be awarded to user who has highest vote up and at least two up-votes, if you don't award this.

EDIT : as @ChrisF Commented. On answers posted after the bounty was started

Comment: On answers posted **after** the bounty was started.

Comment: What about answers that were *edited* after the bounty started?

Comment: @Jon : this answer can not have bounty until awarded by OP