# Community should associate its accounts

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, community-user

Community really ought to associate its accounts, so that it's easier to take a look at its statistics all over the network.

Who knows, it might even get a rep bonus!

Comment: Who would need to know how many times Community has voted?

Comment: @random [SE](http://stackexchange.com/users/-1/community?tab=accounts) shows a full list of associated Community accounts. On the other sites, the only displayed account is Area 51. Bug or by-design?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Accounts tab of the [Community user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community?tab=accounts) shows a full list of associated accounts.

Unfortunately, I cannot find a reference for the [date of addition](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59445/recent-feature-changes-to-stack-exchange).

Comment: According to Google's cache, somewhere before December 5th, but that's still quite a long timeframe: http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:EDHm64zkeJQJ:meta.stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community

Comment: Hmmm, and [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/j0gSP.png) is [interesting](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/104730/how-does-stack-overflow-create-its-question-urls/104732#104732)...!

Comment: @Arjan The community user owns upvotes from accepted answers after migration. I'm currently preparing a question to know *why* Mr. Community frequently looses reputation from bounties.

Comment: There was a little investigation in the comments of [Eeeek! “Community” user got sudden rep boost.. how come?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77115/eeeek-community-user-got-sudden-rep-boost-how-come), but I indeed think we never got to the bottom of that! (Though Nick wrote: *"Just FYI, community now takes over the bounty for users who are deleted but have an active bounty...to ensure it's awarded (half, since it has to be awarded automatically) correctly, since users did put extra effort into answering those questions in many cases."*)