# What happened to Community user accounts?

Tags: discussion, bug, linked-accounts, community-user

I'm pretty sure that the [Community user profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community?tab=summary) used to show all the accounts all over the network.

This is no longer the case - it only shows its Area 51 account.

What happened? Is this by design, or a bug?

Quick research revealed that only couple of months ago [it was implemented](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91565/community-should-associate-its-accounts) so this looks more like a bug.

Comment: I noticed this too but didn't think of posting about it +1

Comment: @Bolt cheers - so it wasn't moderation decision to disassociate the accounts? (aka by design :))

Comment: I have no idea.

Comment: @ShaDowWizArd: Moderation Decisions do not necessarily include all moderators. You also have to differentiate between Moderators and developers. ^^

Comment: @Bobby true enough, but I gather that they have some sort of private communication/board where they share announcements. Might be wrong though. :)

Comment: @ShaDowWizArd - however, the developers still don't announce things. We still have to ask.

Comment: Comparing the [Programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/users/-1) and [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/users/-1) accounts appears to show that they are connected to the **same** [Area 51 account](http://area51.stackexchange.com/users/-1) which only shows itself in the associated accounts tab.

Comment: @ChrisF thanks, I actually recall some problem we had in the past where Area 51 didn't show up in the Accounts tab of users - maybe it's related?

Answer (score 1):

I take it is as design.
As the Community user always exists in all the Stack Exchange sites, listing all the associated accounts would mean to list all the existing Stack Exchange sites (excluding, maybe, the private beta sites). I guess the decision was not to show that information.

Comment: Makes sense, but then why accepting [this feature request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91565/community-should-associate-its-accounts) instead of declining it?

Comment: [meta-tag:status-completed] was added by random. This means that officially, the feature request has not been accepted; it just happened that the code was changed as suggested by the feature request. `:)`

Comment: But he's "only" a moderator so from what I understand, can't change any code..

Comment: That is correct. What I mean is that he noticed the code was already behaving as described, and tagged the question accordingly. There was not an official "Yeah, we like this feature request, and we are going to implement it." `:)`

Comment: Hmm.. interesting. So now a mod will edit again to `status-declined`? :/