# Community user earned reputation?

Tags: support, reputation, community-user

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Eeeek! “Community” user got sudden rep boost.. how come?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77115/eeeek-community-user-got-sudden-rep-boost-how-come)

I just noticed that on [Mathematics](https://math.stackexchange.com/), the Community User currently has **3** reputation points! According to [the reputation listing](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community?tab=reputation#reppage_1-repview_post), he accepted an answer on July 2, earning him 2 reputation points. But I don't see any posts owned by the Community User. How can that happen?

Comment: Hoping @random is composing an answer to the duplicate now! ;-)

Comment: In this case, Community gain reputation because the question was migrated on Mathematics on July 2, but the user who asked the question created the account that site just 6 days ago. It means the account didn't exist when the question was migrated, and the reputation gain for the already accepted answer was passed to Community.