# Why is Community getting reputation?

Tags: support, community-user

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Eeeek! “Community” user got sudden rep boost.. how come?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77115/eeeek-community-user-got-sudden-rep-boost-how-come)

Is our favourite bot, Community, supposed to be getting reputation from suggested edits?

I thought it was always at 1 reputation, but it looks like it has joined the rep hunting crowd: Currently [201 at Programmers](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community), [476 at Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community).

Is this intentional?

Comment: It looks like all the +2s are coming from accepting answers on migrated questions.  Maybe this is done by Community when an accepted answer already exists, but the OP doesn't have an associated account on the target site yet?

Comment: More curiously, how did it vote 52,644 times?

Comment: @Mark: that are the votes of deleted posts.

Comment: @Chichiray SO's posts deleted only have a vote total around 2.5k vs. Programmers's 53k? That seems hard to believe.

Comment: @Mark: and votes on migrated posts from SO of accounts which don't exist on Programmers (I think, they have to originate *somewhere*).

Answer (score 2):

As I understand it, Community's "always" at 1 rep because it absorbs so many downvotes.  But that can be upset temporarily if it hasn't absorbed enough downvotes to counter its most recent rep gain from other things.

Comment: Checking it's rep tab reveals that it also takes the hit for some bounties.