# Why is the Community user accruing reputation from accepts?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, reputation, accepted-answer, community-user

I've noticed that [Community](https://stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community?tab=reputation) is earning reputation from accepting answers:

[image]

Digging a little deeper, I realized all these posts have been migrated from some other SE site. So it looks like instead of having the OP earning +2 from the accept, Community gets it. For example:

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8275726/creating-non-rectangular-clickboxes-for-links/8275727#8275727) was accepted presumably some time after it was answered, ie: after Nov 25th. But if you look at the OP's [reputation tab](https://stackoverflow.com/users/767912/anonymous?tab=reputation) they don't seem to be getting the +2 accept bonus. [Community](https://stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community?tab=reputation) is getting it instead.

*<sub>PS: I noticed a pattern of closing questions related to Community earning reputation being closed as a dupe of [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77115/eeeek-community-user-got-sudden-rep-boost-how-come), but I think this is different.</sub>*

Comment: I thought for certain this had been asked before, but I can't find it...

Comment: @John, this one?: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77115/eeeek-community-user-got-sudden-rep-boost-how-come?lq=1

Answer (score 4):

This is intentional, if the user doesn't exist when rep-changing content is migrated, it's assigned to community, so the other end of the change has no issues.  This is also true for bounties when a user is deleted, etc.

If and when a user registers on the destination site most rep-related things are properly assigned to them on first login, this doesn't include all items though.

Comment: Can't this be fixed by checking whether or not the user exists in the target site and then giving them reputation? I mean, it's already done with upvotes, why are accepts any different?