# Community ♦ user dismissing close-flags as helpful, stealing credit from mods

Tags: bug, status-completed, vote-to-close, moderator-tools, flags

It seems like recent changes to the way flags are handled has introduced some strange behavior.

### A little bit of background

Users who don't yet have the reputation to *vote* to close can flag for moderator attention, select "It doesn't belong here", and then select a close reason from the same set of choices available to close voters. These flags get added to the 10K queue, where they sit for a little while - if a 10K user agrees and *votes* to close, the flag is dismissed (as helpful) by [the Community user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community). If nothing happens, the flag eventually "graduates" to the moderator flag queue...

### And therein lies the problem

If a moderator responds to one of these "close" flags and closes the question without manually dismissing the flag, the Community user dismisses it as "helpful" and the moderator's flag handling count is **not** increased!

**A few months ago:**

[image]

**Today:**

[image]

I would expect the flag, once having been shown in the moderator queue, to behave as any other flag - action on the post that results in automatic dismissal also attributes the dismissal to the moderator who dismissed it.

Comment: @Nine Shog, it doesn't look like close flags are the only ones affected by this. It behaves the same way for any flag for moderator attention (including VLQ, custom reasons, etc.)

Comment: Community taking all the credit *again?!*

Comment: It's definitely not *all* flags, @Null - but you're right, it does seem to include more than just the close-flags.

Comment: @Rudolph, Community is at [530 on SO now](http://stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community) ([almost 8k](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community) on another site), but that used to be [much more](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77115/eeeek-community-user-got-sudden-rep-boost-how-come). Yes, beware: someone is using its reputation [for bounties](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/3957486/revisions)! ;-)

Comment: Where did you take those screenshots?

Comment: We're looking into this.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'm going through and ensuring that all places where flags are dismissed give proper credit to the moderator doing the action.

This will be fixed in the next build.