# Gap in processed flag tally on moderator summary page

Tags: bug, stack-overflow, moderator-tools, flags

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Community ♦ user dismissing close-flags as helpful, stealing credit from mods](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116339/community-user-dismissing-close-flags-as-helpful-stealing-credit-from-mods)

Currently, on the "view recent" link from my moderator summary, it indicates 27 actions that were from processed flags all occurring after 2012-02-06 00:00 UTC.

However, looking at my moderator summary page for the day, it only shows three flags processed.

At some point last night, it seems that there was a window of an hour or two where flags that were processed from the flag queue were not being counted on the summary admin page.

During that time, I would process a flag from the queue, check the page (making sure to refresh properly) and the tally didn't increase.

I can't say if this was happening for other moderators on other sites, or other moderators on Stack Overflow either.  It *seems* that it wasn't, but I wasn't checking other moderator flags at the time.

However, looking at the recent history and the current tally on the day, it is easy to tell that the count was not updating at one point.

I'm also curious how localized this might (or might not) be.

It should be noted that now (after doing one or two flags) it seems that the count is increasing correctly.

Answer (score -1):

In the mod dashboard table, the "flags" column gives you the count of posts flagged for moderator attention that you have handled within the selected range.

The history details page lists your recent moderator actions, and these actions are not limited to handling flags for moderator attention.

So...

If you handle a spam flag, the "flags" number in the table won't increase, but a new action will appear in your details.

If you handle a flag on a comment and delete the comment, the "flags" number in the table won't increase, but a new action will appear in your details.

If you handle a moderator attention flag on a post, the "flags" number in the table will go up one, and a new action iwll appear in your details.

Comment: I appreciate that, but this doesn't answer the question, as I've specifically coordinated the actions with the counts.  Additionally, waffles verified that the admin summary page is not cached, so if I have handled a flag, the tallies should be updated immediately upon refresh.  During that window there were 20+ flags that were just not registering regardless of the fact that I handled those flags directly from the flag queue and verified that I was the one who handled them.

Comment: Are you 100% they were moderator attention flags and not other kinds of flags?

Comment: Yep.  Only from the mod queue.

Comment: I've certainly noticed that not all flags I handled as a mod were getting reflected on the count (speaking strictly about mod flags, not comments or spam).

Comment: "only from the mod queue" doesn't necessarily limit things @casperOne.  There are flags in the mod queue that aren't "flagged for moderator attention", ie, the custom message ones.  Regardless, sit tight, changes coming...