# Why has Community started asking questions?

Tags: discussion, meta, election, community-user

While looking at [What would the community user's reputation be if it was actually counted?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/50959/what-would-the-community-users-reputation-be-if-it-was-actually-counted/158415#158415), I noticed that [the Community user owns exactly 2 posts, both questions on Meta moderator elections](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community?tab=questions):

- https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/111310/november-2011-community-moderator-election
- https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/134509/june-2012-community-moderator-election.

([These two are its only rep-earning posts on the entire network.](https://stackexchange.com/users/-1/community))

Has Community achieved intelligence again? Why is it posting questions? And why only on Meta Stack Overflow? (On other sites, [the moderator elections questions are attributed to regular people](http://meta.askubuntu.com/search?q=election).)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wait. Actually, Community *does* post moderator-election questions on other Meta sites. Looking at the revision history, [Community posted a moderator-election question on Ask Ubuntu](http://meta.askubuntu.com/posts/2408/revisions). Then somebody else edited the question, which placed his own name on the post (so Community didn't show up when I looked).

It seems that [the question list on the `stackexchange.com` user page](https://stackexchange.com/users/-1/community?tab=top) filters out posts on Meta sites. But since Meta Stack Overflow is really a special-cased regular site, Community's 2 posts on Meta are all that show up.